# Rails 3: How to skip duplicate rows on joins with ORDER by multiple columns in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a simple HABTM relationship Books <-> Authors and I'd like to get books by its title and name of the authors:

```
Book.joins(:authors)
    .where("books.title ILIKE 'roman%' OR authors.name ILIKE 'pushkin%'")
    .order("books.id DESC").limit(20).group("books.id")
```

That works perfect.

BUT if i want to sort additionally by Author name i got duplicate row for books that have many authors:

```
Book.joins(:authors)
    .where("books.title ILIKE 'roman%' OR authors.name ILIKE 'pushkin%'")
     .order("books.id DESC, authors.id DESC").limit(20).group("books.id, authors.id")
```

I got something like:

```
id  | title  | ...
123 | Roman1 |   // this book has only 1 author
55  | roman2 |  
55  | roman2 |   // this one hase 2 authors
177 | Roman5 | ... 
etc.
```

How can I merge those rows by `id`  in sql query (btw, Postgres 9.1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the order part, but the group by part. If you include the author, it means you make difference between the book and the author too.

I recommend you to omitt the author.id, and order the list from code, and not is SQL.

Comment: Unfortunately Postgres requires the group by author part. if only i could avoid that...

Comment: When you're grouping, you can only use columns that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or aggregate functions.  That's simply the way SQL works.

Comment: That's why I said to omitt it from the group by AND from the order part.

Comment: Thank you - that's the trick: if i change authors.id -> max(authors.id) - i can skip using authors.id in GROUP BY !